# Java array modifier method

Tags: java, arrays

takes an integer array of length n, where n > 5.  The method returns an integer array of length 10 where the first 1/2 of the array contains elements from the start

My test case:

```
int[] a = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayModifier(a)))
```

output:

```
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Code:

```
public static int[] arrayModifier(int[] a) {
   int ctr = 0;
   int i=0;
   for(int i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
       {
           if(a[i] >= 5) {
               a[i] = a[10];
               ctr ++;
           }
       }
   return ctr;
}
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ??

Comment: 1st: Your code won't compile. `ctr` is an `int` but the method should return `int[]`. 2nd: You modifiy the original array since the 5th index, all following indices will have the value of the 10th index (`a[i] = a[10]`)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to iterate over the whole input array, you're interested only in 5 elements - first five and the last five, which have indexes `a[0..4]` and `a[a.length-5 .. a.length-1]` respectively.

Translating that into code you get:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  newArray[i] = a[i]; // first five
  newArray[i + 5] = a[a.length - 5 + i]; // last five
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
public static int[] arrayModifier(int[] a) {
   int result[] = new int[10];
   int i=0;
   for(i = 0; i<5; i++){
       result[i] = a[i];
       result[10 - i - 1] = a[a.length - i - 1];
   }
   return result;
}
```

If your result array always have the length of 10, then you can just iterate only 5 times. Every time assign two element, one from the beginning and another form the end.